# How do I filter specific rows in Azure Tables using python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have data in a Azure storage table with the following schema:

```
PartitionKey      TimeStamp         Name
..                ...               ...
```

I want to return all entities with name starting with `mem`. I am trying to achieve this in python.

I could only find docs on doing a complete string comparison in filter parameter in the SDK (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Querying-Tables-and-Entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Is there a way to perform a partial comparison?

The equivalent SQL query is

```
SELECT * from table where NAME LIKE mem%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such operators in azure table storage.

But there is a trick(here is a [blog](https://scotthelme.co.uk/hacking-table-storage-like-queries/) about this) you can use for your purpose. Define your $filter like below:

```
"Name ge 'mem' and Name lt 'men'"
```

Here is the test code(for more details, please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-python#query-a-set-of-entities)), and works fine:

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService
from azure.cosmosdb.table.models import Entity

table_service = TableService(account_name='xxx', account_key='xxx')

tasks = table_service.query_entities(
    'your_table_name', filter="Name ge 'mem' and Name lt 'men'")

for task in tasks:
    print(task.Name)
```

The test result at my side:

[image]

Comment: Nice job Ivan! For info about every available filter operators check https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples#writing-filters