# How to filter specific values in Azure Table Storage in a column?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have column called Id in azure table storage as [shown here](https://gist.github.com/ajaykamal3/cc3440ef2c069eeb9518737a6ff65dd4). I would like to query all the rows that contain 'ActPow'. I understood that I can't use "like" here due to limitation of azure table storage and need to use `le` and `ge` for filtering as per documentation. How can I do this for my data? I am using Azure Table Storage SDK for python.

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: @Jahnavi yes. I tried the filter `Id ge 'SH3.PV01.PCS1_1.ActPow' and Id le 'SH8.PV09.PCS9_3.ActPow'`. But it didn't work. It is giving me other rows which doesn't contain `ActPow` as well

Comment: Did you add double quotes for the above expression! Try like this 
`"Id ge 'SH3.PV01.PCS1_1.ActPow' and Id le 'SH8.PV09.PCS9_3.ActPow'"`.

Comment: @Jahnavi yes. I added that and tried. Still the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ***Azure Table Storage SDK for python***, I've written a python script to retrieve the Name/ID from a table entities by filtering through row key.

***I've taken few row entities from your data table and pass query_entities as shown below:***

```py
Table_Service.query_entities(
'<tablename>', filter="Name ge 'SH3.PV01.PCS1_1.ActPow' and Name le 'SH6.PV01.PCS1_1.ActPow'")
```

***Try below script which worked for me successfully:***

```py
from  azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice  import  TableService
from  azure.cosmosdb.table.models  import  Entity
Table_Service = TableService(account_name='jahnaviaea0', account_key='gef7M174ISk1jubiZ7bOzP5cXVIU2XjUEm9G5PX4KjXl19JuAmswip2/77Za30FrmBz0CiQtChol+AStDNIGIw==')
rowouput = Table_Service.query_entities(
'new', filter="Name ge 'SH3.PV01.PCS1_1.ActPow' and Name le 'SH6.PV01.PCS1_1.ActPow'")
for  row  in  rowoutput:
print(row.Name)
```

***Before executing the code,  Install the required*** `azure-cosmosdb-table` ***package***

```py
pip install azure-cosmosdb-table
```

***Output:***

[image]

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418215/how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-in-azure-tables-using-python-sdk) by @Ivan Glasenberg & [SDK sample tables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples#writing-filters).

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what if I have `SH8.PV04.PCS1_3.TmpHSnk1` and `SH6.PV05.PCS1_1.TmpHSnk2` in the data but I want to filter only the rows that contain `ActPow` only

Comment: You can add  `"Name eq 'ActPow'"` to the filter in query_entities. @AjayGanti